# How to make textbox mandatory for certain radio buttons using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with JSP and I have a HTML form in which I have a button at the top which is Process button. Now if I click on that Process button, it shows me a form which has two radio button - `TestClient` and `TestServer`.

It also has `Submit` button in that form.

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/49/).

Now what I am trying to do is -  As soon as I click on `TestClient` radio button, I need to type in `firstName` textbox and `lastName` textbox before pressing Submit button. Meaning these two textbox are mandatory for `TestClient` radio button and if somebody has typed in third textbox for `TestClient` radio button, then it should show error message next to that textbox. But If I am clicking `TestServer` radio button, all the three textbox are mandatory, meaning I need to type in something in all the three textbox.

May be, I can use disable Submit button feature as well if certain conditions are not met along with the proper message next to the textbox?

I am new to jQuery so still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing to do here to avoid confusing your users would be to `hide()` the unnecessary field like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/53/). When the `TestClient` button is selected, the `address` field is hidden, but when the `TestServer` button is selected, it is shown. This avoids confusion with which boxes to fill in: people tend to dislike error messages, even if they are phrased kindly.

Comment: Thanks for the help and it worked fine. I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847945/how-to-hide-labels-whose-value-is-null-or-empty-after-submit-button-is-clicked). See if you can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

## try out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/58/)

for figuring out if the form is submittable, you can use a `submittable` method to detect whether required inputs have a value:

```
// update submit button
function submittable() {
    // get all required fields (needs to happen each time)
    var $required = $('input[required=required]', '#form_process'),
        $submittable = true;
    
    $required.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            // nothing
        } else {
            $submittable = false;
        }
    });
    return $submittable;
}
```

in order for this to work properly, you need to make sure that your universally required inputs have a required attribute and your optionally required address input does not

```
<input name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="firstName" required="required">
<input name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="lastName" required="required">
<input name="address" id="address" placeholder="address">
```

then the `validate` method which will use the `submittable` method to validate the form and disable/enable the button

```
var $submit = $('#submit');

// validate control
function validate() {
    if (submittable()) {
        // you are valid
        //alert('valid');
        $submit.attr('disabled',false);
    } else {
        // you are not valid
        //alert('invalid');
        $submit.attr('disabled',true);
    }
}
```

then you initially run the `validate` method

```
// run initial validation
validate();
```

and then run it on keyup of all the form inputs

```
// run validation on input keyup
$('#form_process input').keyup(function() {
    validate();
});
```

you also need a method to get the currently checked radio that will show/hide the extra input. you also need to make that `address` input required when you need it so that you can include it in the `validate` method:

```
var $address = $('#address'),
    $server = $('#server');

function getChecked() {
    // find currently checked input
    var $checked = $('input[name=client]:checked', '#form_process');
    // if it is server
    if ($checked.attr('id') === 'server') {
        //alert('server!');
        $address.show();
        $address.attr('required',true);
    } else {
        //alert('client!');
        $address.hide();
        $address.attr('required',false);
    }
}
```

in order for this to work properly, you should set one of your radios to checked

```
<input type="radio" name="client" id="client" value="TestClient" checked="checked">TestClient 
<input type="radio" name="client" id="server" value="TestServer">TestServer
```

then you call the `getChecked` method initially and then whenever a radio value changes (along with the validate method):

```
// call initial get checked
getChecked();

// for each radio
$('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
    // when it changes
    $(this).change(function() {
        // get checked radio
        getChecked();
        // run validation
        validate();
    });
});
```

**edit**

I should note that this solution is very specific to this issue. if you were to have more than 2 radios with varying input combinations, the `getChecked()` function would probably need to be a bit more sophisticated.

additionally, `$('input[type=radio]').each()` would need to be more specific if you have multiple radio groups. in which case you should probably add a class to each radio `$('input.specific-radios').each()` or wrap them in a parent `$('.specific-radios-group input[type=radio]').each()`

Comment: Thanks for the help and it worked fine. I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847945/how-to-hide-labels-whose-value-is-null-or-empty-after-submit-button-is-clicked). See if you can help me out.